# Replace leaflet coordinate with parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coordinates, leaflet

I want the leaflet coordinates to be variable. so instead of:

```
var peil = new L.Polygon([
    [52.36889, 4.91501],
    [52.29714, 4.87038],
    [52.30806, 5.04616],
    [52.46772, 4.82849]
    ]);
```

I want something like

```
var peil = new L.Polygon([
      var1,
      var2,
      var3,
      etc.
     ]);
```

Can someone help me with this, I cannot find anything helpful on Google or StackOverflow itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? The argument that is used is just an array of floats. Have you tried reading about javascript and javascript arrays? Downvoted, too localized and no initiative from user.

Comment: Nevermind, allready solved. thank you for flaming me on my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of arrays of floats. Your example of what you want will work fine, you can use variables when creating an [array literal](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/literal-notation.shtml). There are a handfull of ways to skin this cat, here are a couple:

```
var var1, var2, var3, etc;
var1 = [52.36889, 4.91501];
var2 = [52.29714, 4.87038];
var3 = [52.30806, 5.04616];
etc = [52.46772, 4.82849];

//adding the arrays using literal notation
var coordinates = [var1, var2, var3, etc];

//adding the arrays to a new array condensed
var coordinates = new Array(var1,var2,var3,etc);

//adding the arrays to a new array via push
var coordinates = [];
coordinates.push(var1);
coordinates.push(var2);
coordinates.push(var3);
coordinates.push(etc);

//adding the arrays to a new array via index
var coordinates = [];
coordinates[0] = var1;
coordinates[1] = var2;
coordinates[2] = var3;
coordinates[3] = etc;

var peil = new L.Polygon(coordinates);
```